# mssql bcd string manipulation - swap 2 digits in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

It seems i can't figure how to swap two bites of a varchar with eachother in a string . Example :

`string : 6806642004683587 (varchar)`
`end : 8660460240865378`

It should work like this : 68 06 64 20 04 68 35 87 and flip them like 86 60 46 ...

Is there a function in sql that does bcd string manipulation ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap this in a function, but here's the basic code:

```
DECLARE @VAL NVARCHAR(16) = N'6806642004683587';
DECLARE @OUT NVARCHAR(16);

;WITH A(N, S) AS (
    SELECT 1 N, SUBSTRING(@VAL, 1, 2) S
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N+2 N, SUBSTRING(@VAL, N+2, 2) S FROM A WHERE N+2 < LEN(@VAL)
) 
SELECT @OUT = COALESCE(@OUT + '', '') + REVERSE(S) FROM A;

SELECT @VAL, @OUT;

---------------- ----------------
6806642004683587 8660460240865378
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use a `while` loop.

**Query**

```
declare @str as varchar(max);
declare @len as int;
declare @i as int;
declare @ii as int;
declare @res as varchar(max);
declare @res1 as varchar(max);
set @str = '6806642004683587';
set @len = len(@str) / 2;
set @i = 1;
set @ii = 1;
set @res = '';

while @len >= @i
begin
    set @res1 = substring(@str, @ii, 2)
    set @ii = @ii + 2;
    set @i = @i + 1;
    set @res += reverse(@res1)
end

select @str as [actual string], @res as [updated string];
```

**Result**

```
+------------------+------------------+
| actual string    | updated string   |
+------------------+------------------+
| 6806642004683587 | 8660460240865378 |
+------------------+------------------+
```

If the string len is an odd number, and if you need to concatenate the last single character also. Then change `while @len >= @i` to `while @len >= @i - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a number table ,no need of any loops,you also can

```
 ;with cte
    as
    (
    select 
    reverse(substring(@nn,n,2))  as n
    from numbers
    where n<=len(@nn)
    and (n%2=0 or n=1)
    )
    select
    replace(stuff( (SELECT ','+n 
     FROm cte
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'),1,1,''),',','')
```